# PDO's fetchAll() method returns half of the columns the query requests. No exception thrown

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is with Apache 2.2.23, PHP 7 and MySQL 5.6.32. The hosting environment is a Bluehost Shared hosting Web Server.

Here is the database connection function:

```
function connectBlogDatabase() {
$server = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'database_name';
$username = 'database_user';
$password = '1234';
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $server . ';dbname=' . $dbname;
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
    $link = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $_SESSION['error'] .= $ex;
}
return $link;
}
```

Here is the query function:

```
function getMostRecentArticles(int $quantity){
$connection = connectBlogDatabase();
try{
    $sql = "SELECT blog_title, blog_body, blog_description, blog_date FROM blog WHERE published = 1 ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT :quantity;";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':quantity', $quantity, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $blogs = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    return $blogs;
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex;
    $_SESSION['error'] .= "ERROR: Caught Exception \$ex";
    return FALSE;
}
}
```

The query function is used in the following display function. This is simply designed to display the n most recently published blog article links while alternating the css background-color property:

```
function blog_article_links($quantity){
//get a list of the $quantity most recently written blog articles
$articles = getMostRecentArticles($quantity);
$i = 1;
do{
    if($i % 2 === 0){
        //even numbered blog post
        echo "<li class='blog-nav-li flex-box-blog-link background-
1'>";
    } else{
        echo "<li class='blog-nav-li flex-box-blog-link background-
2'>";
    }
    echo "<a class='nav-article-link' 
href='view/blog_template.php'>";
    echo "<h4 class='nav-article-header'>" . $articles['blog_title'] 
. "</h4>";
    echo "<p class='nav-article-description'>" . 
$articles['blog_description'] . "</p>";
    echo "<footer class='article-footer'>";
    echo "<div class='article-footer-social'>";
    echo "<a class='twitter-share-button tweet' 
href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet'>Tweet</a>";
    echo "</div><!-- facebook share button-->";
    echo "<div class='fb-share-button fb-share' data-
href='https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/' data-
layout='button' data-size='small' data-mobile-iframe='true'><a 
class='fb-xfbml-parse-ignore' target='_blank' 
href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php
u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook
.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpr
eparse'>Share</a></div>";
    echo "<time datetime='".$articles["blog_date"] . "' 
class='article-footer-date'>" . $articles['blog_date'] . "</time>";
    echo "</footer></a></li>";
    $i += 1;
}while($i <= $quantity);
}
```

When I run the blog_article_links() function, no error is thrown, and $ex is not displayed. When I use var_dump() inside blog_article_links(), I get the following:

```
" ["blog_description"]=> string(46) "Lorem Ipsum Delta Theda Alpha Omega Pizza Pie." [2]=> string(46) "Lorem Ipsum Delta Theda Alpha Omega Pizza Pie." ["blog_date"]=> string(10) "2017-08-10" [3]=> string(10) "2017-08-10" } }
```

I've used various different parameters in the fetchAll() method, including PDO::FETCH_NUM, explicitly using the default PDO::FETCH_BOTH, and once even used PDO::FETCH_ASSOC just for the hell of it, to see what would change.

None of these created the results I need. I think it has something to do with the

```
FROM blog WHERE published = 1 ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT :quantity;
```

portion of the query. I think PDO is fucking it up because PDO doesn't know how to deal with the ORDER BY and DESC LIMIT keywords.

Now I know for a fact the connectBlogDatabase() function works. There is another query function using this same connectBlogDatabase() function for its PDO object, and that function returns the expected results.

Also, the database user used by connectBlogDatabase() only has SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE permissions.

Comment: So `echo '<pre>'.print_r($blogs, true).'</pre>';` is missing stuff?

Comment: FYI, `$ex` would be an object, not a string.  To get the error message from the Exception object, do `$ex->getMessage();`

Comment: @PatrickQ echoing just the object will still echo out https://3v4l.org/DqNYU

Comment: Avoid putting `;` in your PDO queries. That's only necessary on the MySQL command-line where it needs to know where your query ends.

Comment: What columns are you expecting to get out? The wall of `echo <td>` is making this hard to look at

Comment: `$articles['blog_title']`, etc. inside the `blog_article_links` function doesn't look like it should work. `$articles` is an array of rows, not a single row, right?

Comment: "Don't Panic", you're right. Still, var_dump($articles) should work. The output I showed you was from a var_dump.

Comment: Where did you put the var_dump? It looks like the first part of it is missing. I mean, not necessarily that the first part of the array input to var_dump is missing, but the first part of the var_dump _output_ is not displayed. It should have some `Array (` and opening `{` and whatnot.

Comment: Could some style or HTML issue on your page be preventing the var_dump output from displaying properly? Have you checked the page source to see if maybe the rest of it is there?

Comment: the first part of the var_dump() output is missing. I didn't exclude or forget it. That's actually the core of my concern, and it's what i'm asking about.

You are actually seeing the var_dump() output. That even goes for the developer view of the HTML in the browser. It doesn't make any sense.

I actually copied that from the HTML-developer view, so it isn't CSS being weird.

Comment: That's so strange. I'm at a loss. It doesn't really seem like a PDO problem to me, though. I can't see how PDO would be able to do anything that would chop off the first part of the var_dump output. Then again, I don't really see how _anything_ would do that.

Comment: do you have any suggestions as to where I should go from here? maybe a debugger and stack trace? I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Yeah, I think that sounds like the logical next step. Honestly I think the debugger usually isn't that necessary with PHP, but it's definitely useful when things get weird.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$articles = getMostRecentArticles($quantity);` in your `blog_article_links` function, `$articles` gets the value of the `$stmt->fetchAll();` expression in that function.

`$articles` will be a multidimensional array, where each inner array is a row from the query results. So when you do `$articles['blog_title']`, `$articles['blog_description']`, etc., those are undefined indexes.

There are different ways to fix this. One way would be to separate your `blog_article_links` function into two functions, one that prints out a single article and another that iterates the list returned from the database and calls the single output function for each one.

Get the list and output it with one function

```
function blog_article_links($quantity) {
    //get a list of the $quantity most recently written blog articles
    $articles = getMostRecentArticles($quantity);
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($articles as $article) {
        if ($i % 2 === 0){
            //even numbered blog post
            echo "<li class='blog-nav-li flex-box-blog-link background-1'>";
        } else {
            echo "<li class='blog-nav-li flex-box-blog-link background-2'>";
        }
        blog_article_link($article);
        echo "</li>";
        $i += 1;
    }
}
```

The helper function formats and outputs a single article

```
function blog_article_link($article) {
    echo "<a class='nav-article-link' href='view/blog_template.php'>
          <h4 class='nav-article-header'>$article[blog_title]</h4>
          <p class='nav-article-description'>$article[blog_description]</p>
          <footer class='article-footer'>
              <div class='article-footer-social'>
                  <a class='twitter-share-button tweet' href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet'>Tweet</a>
               </div>
               <!-- facebook share button-->
               <div class='fb-share-button fb-share' data-href='https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/' data-layout='button' data-size='small' data-mobile-iframe='true'>
                   <a class='fb-xfbml-parse-ignore' target='_blank' href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse'>
                       Share
                   </a>
               </div>
               <time datetime='$article[blog_date]' class='article-footer-date'>
                   $article[blog_date]
               </time>
           </footer>
       </a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get it right, but I still don't know why it went wrong in the first place.

I only had 2 blog articles stored in the database. I inserted a 3rd blog article and refreshed the web page. It worked.

That's all I had to do, but that still doesn't explain the fact that it wasn't previously showing up in the developer view in-browser.